# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to build an android app that uses google's speech api to convert a simple audio file into text and display it in a textview using Java. I followed the quickstart tutorial of google to setup the api. I also setup the environment variable and initialized gcloud. But when I build my app, I keep getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

Update: It works fine in eclipse, but not in android studio.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: in case the environment variable is set and points to the right file, you could try and restart your IDE, i know visual studio has this issue where if you update Path and the IDE is open, it is not aware of the changes until you restart it just like command prompt.

Comment: I already tried that, didn't work though.

Comment: any solution for this ?